# Recaptcha breaking with attribute name="submit" on button

Tags: recaptcha

I think I may have come across a bug, or this could be a known thing. When I have the attribute name=”submit” in my submit button that contains the data-sitekey and data-callback, I get an “Uncaught (in promise) TypeError” in my console and it fails to continue doing anything.

As soon as I change the name attribute value to something other than submit it works.

I tried reporting this as a bug to recaptcha but there email for reporting bugs is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying a different captcha version. Invisible recaptcha is a new and better way of secority.

With a wrapper widget it can be a great solution with click functionality as well.
Have a look at this widget: https://www.custom-captcha.com/

```js
CustomCaptcha.init("<your reCaptcha v3 siteKey>");
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/custom-recaptcha/dist/custom_captcha.min.css"></link>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/custom-recaptcha/dist/custom_captcha.min.js"></script>
<captcha required></captcha>
```

Please note: The snippet above just shows the widget itself, and cannot work because there is no valid captcha key for the snippet site.

By default the widget has the website favicon as icon (which I think is a really nice feature) but it can be changed.